# F2FS partition does not mount, fsck.f2fs does not resolve. I want to recover the files

Tags: backup, data-recovery, encryption, motorola-moto-g

I made a backup of my phone's userdata partition with the command (because the /data is not mounting):

`dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata of=/usb_otg/userdata.img`

I need the files that are on the userdata partition. If anyone know a method of recovery that is also accepted.

**INFO**

- Whatever I type, be it number, letter, or symbol, it accepts and shows it.
  [image]
- /data partition doesn’t mount.
- I already used fsck.f2fs but it doesn't solve.
- I found this in recovery.log:
- E: Bad Magic for real block device 
  Could not mount /data and unable to find crypto footer
- tw_includ_crypto=true
- crypto ready=1
- ro.crypto.type=file
- ro.crypto.state=encrypted

**Fsck.f2fs log**

```
I:operation_start: 'Repair Partition'
Repairing Data using fsck.f2fs...
I:Repair command: /sbin/fsck.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p42
        Info: No support kernel version!
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 25009920 (12211 MB)
Info: MKFS version
  "Linux version 3.10.49-gd8d6af5 (hudsoncm@ilclbld35) (gcc version 4.8 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 3 03:35:22 CDT 2017"
Info: FSCK version
  from "3.10.108-Lynx-v2.5+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 20 11:16:12 IST 2020"
    to "3.10.108-NPD26.48-24-1-g285c0940a98 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 19 14:51:51 UTC 2020"
Info: superblock features = 1 :  encrypt
Info: superblock encrypt level = 0, salt = 00000000000000000000000000000000
Info: total FS sectors = 25009920 (12211 MB)
Info: CKPT version = 7b4b2
Info: Found valid nat_bits in checkpoint
Info: checkpoint state = 281 :  allow_nocrc nat_bits unmount
[ASSERT] (sanity_check_nid: 372)  --> nid[0x3] ino is 0

[FSCK] Unreachable nat entries                        [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] SIT valid block bitmap checking                [Ok..]
[FSCK] Hard link checking for regular file            [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] valid_block_count matching with CP             [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] valid_node_count matcing with CP (de lookup)   [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] valid_node_count matcing with CP (nat lookup)  [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] valid_inode_count matched with CP              [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] free segment_count matched with CP             [Ok..] [0x17a6]
[FSCK] next block offset is free                      [Ok..]
[FSCK] fixing SIT types
[FSCK] other corrupted bugs                           [Fail]
Info: Write valid nat_bits in checkpoint

Done.
I:/sbin/fsck.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p42 process ended with RC=0
Done.
```

**Recovery.log**

```
Starting TWRP 3.4.0-0-35475b1d on Sat Jan 10 18:51:21 1970 
(pid 209)
RECOVERY_SDCARD_ON_DATA := true
I:Lun file '/sys/devices/platform/msm_hsusb/gadget/lun0/file'
TW_INCLUDE_CRYPTO := true
I:Found brightness file at '/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness'
I:Got max brightness 255 from '/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/max_brightness'
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 255
I:LANG: en
Starting the UI...
setting DRM_FORMAT_RGB565 and GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565
cannot find/open a drm device: No such file or directory
fb0 reports (possibly inaccurate):
  vi.bits_per_pixel = 32
  vi.red.offset   =   0   .length =   8
  vi.green.offset =   8   .length =   8
  vi.blue.offset  =  16   .length =   8
setting GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
double buffered
framebuffer: 0 (720 x 1280)
Using fbdev graphics.
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 255
TW_SCREEN_BLANK_ON_BOOT := true
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 0
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 255
I:Loading package: splash (/twres/splash.xml)
I:Load XML directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/splash.xml' directly
I:Checking resolution...
I:Scaling theme width 0.666667x and height 0.666667x, offsets x: 0 y: 0 w: 0 h: 0
I:Loading resources...
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Loading page splash
I:Switching packages (splash)
I:Blacklisting input device: hbtp_vm
=> Linking mtab
=> Processing /etc/twrp.fstab for SAR-detection
I:Reading /etc/twrp.fstab
I:Done processing fstab files
I:SAR-DETECT: SAR System detected
=> Processing /etc/twrp.fstab
I:Reading /etc/twrp.fstab
I:Processing '/system'
I:Created '/system_root' folder.
I:Processing '/system_image'
I:Processing '/data'
I:Processing '/cache'
I:Processing '/boot'
I:Processing '/recovery'
I:Processing '/persist'
I:Created '/persist' folder.
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: Pre-fix date and time: 1970-01-10--18-51-21
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: Setting time offset from file /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/since_epoch
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: will attempt to use the ats files now.
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: no ats files found, leaving untouched!
I:Processing '/firmware'
I:Processing '/misc'
I:Processing '/external_sd'
I:Created '/external_sd' folder.
I:Processing '/usb_otg'
I:Created '/usb_otg' folder.
I:Done processing fstab files
I:Setting up '/data' as data/media emulated storage.
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
E:Bad magic for real block device /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/metadata
Could not mount /data and unable to find crypto footer.
I:Setting up '/data' as data/media emulated storage.
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
Failed to mount '/data' (No such file or directory)
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
Unable to recreate /data/media folder.
I:Backup folder set to '/data/media/TWRP/BACKUPS/0021404064'
I:Settings storage is '/data/media'
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
Updating partition details...
Failed to mount '/data' (No such file or directory)
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
I:Unable to mount '/external_sd'
I:Actual block device: '', current file system: 'auto'
I:Unable to mount '/usb_otg'
I:Actual block device: '', current file system: 'auto'
...done
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
Unable to mount storage
I:Unmounting main partitions...


Partition Logs:
/system_root | /dev/block/mmcblk0p41 | Size: 2283MB Used: 1087MB Free: 1195MB Backup Size: 1087MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent Mount_Read_Only 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p41
   Display_Name: System
   Storage_Name: System
   Backup_Path: /system_root
   Backup_Name: system
   Backup_Display_Name: System
   Storage_Path: /system_root
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/system_image | /dev/block/mmcblk0p41 | Size: 2320MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p41
   Display_Name: System Image
   Storage_Name: system_image
   Backup_Path: /system_image
   Backup_Name: system_image
   Backup_Display_Name: System Image
   Storage_Path: /system_image
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/data | /dev/block/mmcblk0p42 | Size: 0MB Used: 0MB Free: 0MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_During_Factory_Reset Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent Can_Be_Encrypted Has_Data_Media Can_Encrypt_Backup Use_Userdata_Encryption Is_Storage Is_Settings_Storage 
   Symlink_Path: /data/media
   Symlink_Mount_Point: /sdcard
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p42
   Crypto_Key_Location: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/metadata
   Display_Name: Data
   Storage_Name: Internal Storage
   Backup_Path: /data
   Backup_Name: data
   Backup_Display_Name: Data
   Storage_Path: /data/media
   Current_File_System: f2fs
   Fstab_File_System: f2fs
   Backup_Method: files
   Mount_Flags: 3078, Mount_Options: discard,inline_xattr,inline_data
   MTP_Storage_ID: 65537

/cache | /dev/block/mmcblk0p40 | Size: 254MB Used: 70MB Free: 183MB Backup Size: 70MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_During_Factory_Reset Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p40
   Display_Name: Cache
   Storage_Name: Cache
   Backup_Path: /cache
   Backup_Name: cache
   Backup_Display_Name: Cache
   Storage_Path: /cache
   Current_File_System: f2fs
   Fstab_File_System: auto
   Backup_Method: files

/boot | /dev/block/mmcblk0p31 | Size: 16MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p31
   Display_Name: Boot
   Storage_Name: boot
   Backup_Path: /boot
   Backup_Name: boot
   Backup_Display_Name: Boot
   Storage_Path: /boot
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/recovery | /dev/block/mmcblk0p32 | Size: 16MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p32
   Display_Name: Recovery
   Storage_Name: recovery
   Backup_Path: /recovery
   Backup_Name: recovery
   Backup_Display_Name: Recovery
   Storage_Path: /recovery
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/persist | /dev/block/mmcblk0p29 | Size: 3MB Used: 0MB Free: 3MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped IsPresent Mount_To_Decrypt 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p29
   Display_Name: persist
   Storage_Name: persist
   Backup_Path: /persist
   Backup_Name: persist
   Backup_Display_Name: persist
   Storage_Path: /persist
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files
   Mount_Flags: 1030, Mount_Options: barrier=1,noauto_da_alloc

/firmware | /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 | Size: 35MB Used: 31MB Free: 3MB Backup Size: 31MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped IsPresent Mount_To_Decrypt Mount_Read_Only 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
   Display_Name: firmware
   Storage_Name: firmware
   Backup_Path: /firmware
   Backup_Name: firmware
   Backup_Display_Name: firmware
   Storage_Path: /firmware
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files
   Mount_Flags: 6, Mount_Options: barrier=0,context=u:object_r:fsg_file:s0

/misc | /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 | Size: 0MB
   Flags: IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p9
   Display_Name: misc
   Storage_Name: misc
   Backup_Path: /misc
   Backup_Name: misc
   Backup_Display_Name: misc
   Storage_Path: /misc
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/external_sd |  | Size: 0MB Used: 0MB Free: 0MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Wipe_Available_in_GUI Removable Is_Storage 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk1p1
   Alternate_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk1
   Display_Name: MicroSD Card
   Storage_Name: MicroSD Card
   Backup_Path: /external_sd
   Backup_Name: external_sd
   Backup_Display_Name: MicroSD Card
   Storage_Path: /external_sd
   Current_File_System: auto
   Fstab_File_System: auto
   Backup_Method: files
   MTP_Storage_ID: 65538

/usb_otg |  | Size: 0MB Used: 0MB Free: 0MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Wipe_Available_in_GUI Removable Is_Storage 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/sda1
   Alternate_Block_Device: /dev/block/sda
   Display_Name: USB-OTG
   Storage_Name: USB-OTG
   Backup_Path: /usb_otg
   Backup_Name: usb_otg
   Backup_Display_Name: USB-OTG
   Storage_Path: /usb_otg
   Current_File_System: auto
   Fstab_File_System: auto
   Backup_Method: files
   MTP_Storage_ID: 65539

I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
I:Unable to mount '/data'
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
Failed to mount '/data' (No such file or directory)
I:Actual block device: '/dev/block/mmcblk0p42', current file system: 'f2fs'
I:Unable to mount /data/media during GUI startup.
I:Loading package: TWRP (/twres/ui.xml)
I:Load XML directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/uk.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/tr.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sv.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sk.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/ru.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pt_PT.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pt_BR.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/nl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/it.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/hu.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/fr.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/es.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/en.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/el.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/de.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/cz.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/en.xml' directly
parsing languageFile
parsing languageFile done
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/ui.xml' directly
I:Checking resolution...
I:Scaling theme width 0.666667x and height 0.666667x, offsets x: 0 y: 0 w: 0 h: 0
I:Loading resources...
I:Failed to load image from indeterminate013, error -1
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Including file: /twres/portrait.xml...
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/portrait.xml' directly
I:Loading resources...
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Loading page main
I:Loading page main2
I:Loading page install
I:Loading page flash_confirm
I:Loading page flash_zip
I:Loading page flash_done
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120659/discussion-on-question-by-joaquim-alves-de-souza-how-i-extract-a-file-userdata-i).

Comment: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/3171#issuecomment-729814931

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1225447